# How to add script type for aptana html editor in order to recognise "dojo/method" type

Tags: eclipse, dojo, aptana

I am using the aptana studio 3 plugin in eclipse indigo to create html/dojo files.

My problem is that `<script type="dojo/method">` is not treated as a javascript block. 
When I use `<script type="text/javascript">` everything (code completion, highlighting, formatting) works ok.

Is there a way to have "dojo/method" treated the same as "text/javascript"?